# Android receive RTP/UDP audio stream from VLC/ffmpeg

Tags: android, ffmpeg, audio-streaming, vlc, rtp

I was searching for a good answer for half a day, but I am a beginner at this stuff and I would appreciate any help.

What I would like to achieve is to stream audio (mp3 files) within ffmpeg or vlc and receive it on an Android device by udp/rtp.

This is what I was able to figure out myself sofar:

1) There is Android class AudioStream and RTPStream. What I don't know is how to use it. For example I create a stream via ffmpeg with: `ffmpeg -re -i mymp3.mp3 -ar 8000 -acodec copy -f rtp rtp://192.168.0.100:5533`, where `192.168.0.100` is the address of my Android device. Now I would like to receive it and play it.

I found something like this on Stack:

```
AudioStream audioStream;
AudioGroup audioGroup;
AudioCodec codec = AudioCodec.PCMU;
StrictMode.ThreadPolicy policy = new StrictMode.ThreadPolicy.Builder().permitNetwork().build();
StrictMode.setThreadPolicy(policy);
AudioManager audio = (AudioManager)getSystemService(AUDIO_SERVICE);
audio.setMode(AudioManager.MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION);
audioGroup = new AudioGroup();
audioGroup.setMode(AudioGroup.MODE_NORMAL);
InetAddress inetAddress;
try {
    inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName("163.11.62.208");
    audioStream = new AudioStream(inetAddress);
    audioStream.setMode(RtpStream.MODE_RECEIVE_ONLY);
    audioStream.setCodec(codec);
    InetAddress inetAddressRemote = InetAddress.getByName("163.11.169.206");
    audioStream.associate(inetAddressRemote, 5004);
    audioStream.join(audioGroup);
}
```

What is the first inetAddress `163.11.62.208` and what is the second one `163.11.169.206`? Shoudln't I just give an address of a stream?

2) Can I submit only streams in PCMU format? Can I stream mp3 files?

3) Is it even possible?

Comment: Any updates about this?

Answer (score 4):

I've implemented Cisco Jabber integration with our server and Android and had similar set up.

```
audioStream = new AudioStream(inetAddress)
```

inetAddress(163.11.62.208) is the local network address of that android device.
We get it using the following:

```
WifiManager wifiMgr = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
WifiInfo wifiInfo = wifiMgr.getConnectionInfo();
int ip = wifiInfo.getIpAddress();
String ipAddress = Formatter.formatIpAddress(ip);
Log.w(TAG, "ipAddress=" + ipAddress);
inetAddress = InetAddress.getByName(ipAddress);
```

There is may be other ways, i'm not and Android developer.

`audioStream.associate(inetAddressRemote, 5004)`

inetAddressRemote(163.11.169.206) is the remote address of the server from which you'll be sending audio to Android.

`5004` is the port to send audio to and from on both Android and server side.
Now there is a catch - make sure the local port you send audio from the server to Android is also a 5004. For example test audio stream:

```
ffmpeg -re -f lavfi -i aevalsrc="sin(400*2*PI*t)" -map 0:0  -c:a pcm_mulaw -b:a 64k -ar 8000 -f rtp rtp://163.11.62.208:5004?localrtpport=5004
```